# How to Make AWS Infrastructure perform comparable to local server running on a MacBook Pro

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have a web application that is caching data in CSV files, and then in response to an HTTP request, reading the CSV files into memory, constructing a JavaScript Object, then sending that Object as JSON to the client.

When I run this on my Local Server on my Macbook Pro (2022, Chip: Apple M1 Pro, 16GB Memory, 500GB Hard Drive), the 24 CSV files at about 15MB each are all read in about 2.5 seconds, and then the subsequent processing takes another 3 seconds, for a total execution time of about 5.5 seconds.

When I deploy this application to AWS, however, I am struggling to create a comparably performant environment.

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to spin up an EC2 instance, and then attaching an EBS volume to store the CSV files. I know that as the EBS is running on a separate instance, there is possible network latency, but my understanding is typically pretty negligible as far as overall effect on performance.

What I have tried thus far:

- Using a Compute focused instance (c5.4xlarge) which is automatically EBS optimized. Then using a Provisioned IOPS (io2) with 1000 GiB storage and 400 IOPS. (Performance, about 10 seconds total)
- Using a High Throughput EBS volume, which is supposed to offer greater performance for sequential read jobs (like what I imagined reading a CSV file would be), but that actually performed a little worse than the Provisioned IOPS EBS instance. (Performance, about 11 seconds total)

Can anyone offer any recommendations for which EC2 Instance and EBS Volume should be configured to achieve comparable performance with my local machine? I don't expect to get it matching exactly, but do expect that it can be closer than about twice as slow as the local server.

Comment: When measuring, did you split out the network request/response latency so that you're comparing like with like here? Just trying to understand what you measured.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jarmod! I did. Specifically, I'm using Date.getTime() and console.logs on the server track how long the CSV file read portion and the object construction portion takes respectively. I can then compare my local server logs and my ec2 logs as apples to apples.

Comment: For Example, from my Local Server:
`Reading Cache Complete: 2627.547ms`
`Construction Complete: 5168.129ms (Total time)`

Comment: From AWS:
`Aug 20 17:37:08 ip-172-31-23-120 web: Reading Cache Complete: 4498.809ms`
`Aug 20 17:37:12 ip-172-31-23-120 web: Construction Complete: 9234.544ms`

Comment: EC2 instances have local instance store which is local to the physical host, unlike EBS which is network attached. That instance store is ephemeral so don’t use it to persist data across reboot/restart but it can be used for local file storage and access. I’m not 100% sure how it’s exposed to a Beanstalk app but presume it can be and that it will typically be faster than network-attached storage. Perhaps something for you to investigate.

Comment: Beware of using Amazon EBS volumes with Provisioned IOPS -- they cost quite a bit extra and might not be worthwhile if you are just loading short bursts of information. As @jarmod mentioned, _some_ EC2 instance types come with 'instance store', which is a directly-attached disk which provides the fastest performance.

Comment: Appreciate the replies! Thanks for calling out local instance storage and to be aware of higher costs with Provisioned IOPS. I'm also looking into enabling the instance to be EBS optimized. To address the other part of the question, do you have any idea what can be done to increase the CPU performance in the construction phase? I see there are different processors used between instances (like AWS Graviton3, or Intel), but compute optimized instances appear to be more of the ratio of CPUS to memory, not inherently more powerful CPUS.